# How to save generated numbers of array in session for the other php file?

Tags: php, forms, session

Here is code for the 1st php file:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
              Size of array: <input type="number" name="size">
        <input type="submit" name="Send" button style="width:700px;height:250px" value="Show array"></span></p> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
  session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['Send']))
    {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['size']; $i ++) 
            {
                $random[] = rand(0, 10);
            }
            $_SESSION['random'] = $random;
            var_dump($_SESSION['random']);
            //sort($random);


         echo "<br>";
         echo "<br>";
         echo "Amount of array's elements: ";
         echo '<strong>'.count($random).'</strong>';    
         header('Location: 2nd_form.php');
         exit();
    }
?>
```

And here is code for the 2nd file:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
//session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['random']);
?>
```

So, how to save array which is at the 1st form and code must save it for the 2nd file ? Pls help :-(

Comment: `session_start()` is missing from the first file

Comment: sorry ,yes.....

Comment: what do you mean by "save array" ? write to a file?

Comment: No, i mean, i can generate array, then i see it on screen, ok, but, when i click at the 2nd form, this array saves, and i can see it also at the 2nd form, but already without textbox'es and button....that's what i need

Comment: you're also outputting before header which is most likely why your code failed. Enable error reporting.

Comment: I really dont understand what you are asking for here.

Comment: Maybe any of u can fix my errors ? i really dont know what to do right now! :-(

Comment: _"fix my errors"_ - we don't know about any errors yet!

Comment: _"but already without textbox'es and button"_ - where should textboxes appear and why? The second file does nothing but output `$_SESSION['random']`

Comment: at the 2nd form i see `string(6) "random"` - instead of array, which is at the 1st form

Comment: at the 1st form i see this `array(6) { [0]=> int(9) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(10) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(10) [5]=> int(6) } ` right now and this array must saved into  the 2nd form

Comment: @Jeff "where should textboxes appear and why" - there must not appear smth, there just need be showed array,which is generated at the 1st form

Comment: Put `session_start()` at the beginning of the first file. It has to be before any of the HTML that you show.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: @Barmar did not help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this will work with you

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Send']))
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['size']; $i ++) 
    {
        $random[] = rand(0, 10);
    }
    $_SESSION['random'] = $random;
    //var_dump($_SESSION['random']);
    //use die to stop script and do var_dump
    //die();
    //
    //dont print anything before header
    //
    header('Location: 2nd_form.php');
    exit();
}else{
    ?>
        <html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
              Size of array: <input type="number" name="size">
        <input type="submit" name="Send" button style="width:700px;height:250px" value="Show array"></span></p> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?PHP
}
?>
```

2nd_form.php:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
//session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['random']);
?>
```